# Is 300 euros a month enough to live on in Portugal?

Tags: portugal

I am a student and I got a scholarship to live in Portugal (Lisbon) for 9 months. The scholarship covers accommodation, health insurance as well as books and fees for the university. So basically I will need to pay for food, transportation and fun.

They are giving me 300 euros each month. Will that be enough?

I can't ask my family for money because they can't help. So I will await any advice here.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the university would give such a scholarship and stipend without considering that you should be able to survive there. Talk to them and make sure they haven't made any assumptions (such as that you would be able to get help from your family). That said, I think you can do it, but you have to be very careful with your money. No big trips. Just basic food and local touristy sites. It is unlikely you will get many more opportunities in this life. Probably best to just go for it.

Comment: that is the think, i have been watiing for this program for 3 years and i am applying to so many schools and scholarships and now i got one but i see that erasmus people took more money that is why i am afraid. are you from portugal please?

Comment: @SemanotniBarbigano, No not from Portugal. But I've done several trips throughout Europe where my finances were questionable at best. Good memories (for the most part).